# How to set the default value of directive attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a custom element directing in AngularJS. My element will be used like this:

```
<my-element my-attribute="false"></my-element>
```

If the user does NOT set `my-attribute`, I want it to default to `true`. How do I give the directive attribute a default value? Currently, I have the following:

```
myApp.directive('myElement', function ($window) {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      myAttribute: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {

    },
    template: '<div>Hello <span ng-if="myAttribute == true">, World</span></div>'
  };
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Make the attribute optional

First, be sure to make the attribute optional. With your current code, if your directive is used like that…

```
<!-- Notice the absence of attribute -->
<my-element></my-element>
```

… then AngularJS will throw a NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION exception as soon as you'll try to set a value to `$scope.myAttribute`. So, as said [in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object), add an interrogation point in your scope definition:

```
scope: {
    myAttribute: '=?',
},
```

### Define the default value

Then, you can simply set the default value in your controller:

```
controller: function ($scope) {
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.myAttribute)) {
        $scope.myAttribute = true;
    }
},
```